# Error sorting dictionary by ascending key value

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a userform that contains a combobox that's populated from the unique items in a worksheet column. I'm trying to sort the keys that represent the items in the combobox in ascending order using the below code, but I'm getting an "Object variable or With block variable not set" error:

```
Public Function funcSortKeysByLengthDesc(dctList As Object) As Object
Dim curKey As Variant
Dim key As Variant
Dim itX As Integer
Dim itY As Integer
Dim arrTemp() As Variant
Dim d As Object

'Only sort if more than one item in the dict
If dctList.Count > 1 Then

    'Populate the array
    ReDim arrTemp(dctList.Count)
    itX = 0
    For Each curKey In dctList
        arrTemp(itX) = curKey
        itX = itX + 1
    Next

    For itX = 0 To (dctList.Count - 2)
        For itY = (itX + 1) To (dctList.Count - 1)
            If arrTemp(itX) > arrTemp(itY) Then
                curKey = arrTemp(itY)
                arrTemp(itY) = arrTemp(itX)
                arrTemp(itX) = curKey
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'Create the new dictionary
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For itX = 0 To UBound(arrTemp)
        d.Add arrTemp(itX), dctList(itX)
    Next

    Set funcSortKeysByLengthDesc = d
Else
    Set funcSortKeysByLengthDesc = dctList
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Doesn't dictionary require two arguments (item and key)? Looks like you're only storing key?

Comment: The syntax for a `Dictionary` isn't the same as for an `array` (which you have written). You add items to a Dictionary like so: `d.Add key, item` ( https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/187234).

Comment: I'm trying to copy a sorted dictionary object to another dictionary object. How would you fix this line of code 'd(arrTemp(itX)) = dctList(arrTemp(itX))'?

Comment: I ended up using 'For Each key In dctList.Keys
            d.Add key, dctList(key)
        Next' to copy the contents of one dictionary object to another. The keys are still not getting sorted. Any ideas?

Comment: I updated my original code to reflect the changes that I made.

Comment: You've bubble sorted an array of keys but your last loop is just duplicating the passed `dctList`. You need to loop through the sorted array: `For itx = 0 to Ubound(arrTemp)` and add each original `dctList` item by sorted array key: `d.Add arrTemp(itx), dctList(itx)`

Comment: @Ambie I made the changes that you requested, but the function still does not sort. If you create a simple test case of string non-sorted keys, you'll see that not only does the function not sort, but it inserts an integer for each item in the key. I updated my original code with the changes you requested .

Comment: Edit your question with 2 or 3 sanple values and I'll post an answer for you.

Comment: The following code populates a combobox with the unique values from a worksheet column; these items are stored in a dictionary object:: 'cbNames.Clear
    
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With d
        For Each rCell In ws.Range("C3", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
            If Not .exists(rCell.Value) Then
                .Add rCell.Value, Nothing
            End If
        Next rCell
        
        Call funcSortDictByKeyAscending(d) 'This is where the keys should be sorted
        
        cbNames.List = .Keys
    End With'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you're using a `Dicionary` for this task, but I've assumed it's required elsewhere in your project, so I've tried to dovetail mine into your existing code.

If you are only putting sorted cells into a `ComboBox` then reading the cells into an array, removing duplicates and sorting that array, then populating the `ComboBox` would be simpler. There are plenty of examples of how to do each of these tasks on this site, so I won't reproduce them here.

Here's the code for you:

```
Sub RunMe()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim dctItem As String
    Dim dctArray() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim d As Object
    Dim v As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Code to poulate a few "C" cells
    ws.Cells(3, "C").Resize(10).Value = Application.Transpose(Array("Z", "Y", "X", "W", "W", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A"))
    UserForm1.Show False

    'Clear the combobox
    UserForm1.cbNames.Clear

    'Create the dictionary
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each rCell In ws.Range("C3", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        dctItem = CStr(rCell.Value2)
        If Not d.Exists(dctItem) Then
            d.Add dctItem, dctItem
        End If
    Next

    'Convert the dictionary items to an array
    Debug.Print "PRE-SORT"
    ReDim dctArray(1 To d.Count)
    i = 1
    For Each v In d.Items
        dctArray(i) = v
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print v
    Next

    'Bubble sort the array
    dctArray = BubbleSort(dctArray)

    'Populate the dictionary and combobox
    Debug.Print "POST-SORT"
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = LBound(dctArray) To UBound(dctArray)
        d.Add dctArray(i), dctArray(i)
        UserForm1.cbNames.AddItem dctArray(i)
        Debug.Print dctArray(i)
    Next

End Sub
Private Function BubbleSort(tempArray As Variant) As Variant
    'Uses Microsoft's version: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/133135
    Dim temp As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim noExchanges As Integer

    ' Loop until no more "exchanges" are made.
    Do
        noExchanges = True

        ' Loop through each element in the array.
        For i = 1 To UBound(tempArray) - 1

            ' If the element is greater than the element
            ' following it, exchange the two elements.
            If tempArray(i) > tempArray(i + 1) Then
                noExchanges = False
                temp = tempArray(i)
                tempArray(i) = tempArray(i + 1)
                tempArray(i + 1) = temp
            End If
        Next i
    Loop While Not (noExchanges)

    BubbleSort = tempArray

End Function
```